# Exit C# application from second form

Tags: c#

How do I exit a C# application completely from the second form when the user presses the X button?

This is my code so far:

**Form1.cs**

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            String cellValue;
            cellValue = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            var form2 = new Form2(cellValue);
            this.Hide();
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

        switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            case DialogResult.No:
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Form2.cs**

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

    switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
    {
        case DialogResult.No:
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{


   DialogResult dgResult = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); 
    if(dgResult==DialogResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;

      else
     //here  you can use  Environment.Exit  which is not recomended because it does not generate a message loop to notify others form
      Environment.Exit(1);  
        //or  you can use
         //Application.Exit();  
}
```

Comment: The dialog appears three times for some reason and the user has to click on "Yes" each time otherwise the program crashes

Comment: try it now  please and let me know if something goes  wrong yet

Comment: Same thing - its really odd :-S

Comment: Might it be worth adding that I have the this code on Form1.cs - http://pastebin.com/4zXx9g5A

Comment: try with environment  exit as application.exit generate a looping message

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, sounds like this is a workable solution:

```
private bool userRequestedExit = false;
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (this.userRequestedExit) {
        return;
    }

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

    switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
    {
        case DialogResult.No:
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        default:
            this.userRequestedExit = true;
            Application.Exit();
            break;
    }
}
```