# Exit C# Form Errors

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to write a program that opened a certain form based on certain criteria. In this particular case, if the shift key is down it will call Form1. If the key is not down, it will check the registry for a key. If the key is not there, it will load Form1. If the key IS there, it will do some checking, load the value and load form2.

The odd behavior I am seeing is that if Form1 gets loaded - either thru the shift key being held down, or by the reg key not being there, if the user clicks on the X in the upper right, it returns BACK to the Program.cs code from whence it came and does not exit the appliaction.

here is part of the code from Program.cs. I wanted to do the checking in Program.cs so I didn;t have to load and hide forms.

```
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Shift key held down");
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }

            using (var hkcu = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64))
            using (var key = hkcu.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\clpCopy"))
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    hkcu.Close();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Key not found."); 
                    Application.Run(new Form1());
                    //MessageBox.Show("Returning from Form 1.");                    
                }
            }
```

On Form1 I have added Form1_FormClosing to Form1.cs to catch the form close:

```
        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

But when you click the X on Form1, it doesn't exit the app, it returns BACK to Program.cs and continues on with the rest of the code.

I have a Cancel button on Form1 which works and closes the app.

How can I force the form to close if I click on X? Why does it go back to the code in Program.cs?

Comment: "But when you click the X on Form1, it doesn't exit the app, it returns BACK to Program.cs and continues on with the rest of the code." - That's what it's meant to do.

Comment: Maybe you should actually read the documentation for the `Application.Exit` method. Maybe you should always read the relevant documentation, especially when things don't work as you expect.

Comment: Application.Exit() merely causes Application.Run() to return.  Just add `return;` after the first Application.Run() call to fix the bug.  So the program exits Main() and terminates.  Putting the rest of the code inside an `else {}` block is another way.

Comment: Have you tried a `return` statement to exit the Main routine?

Comment: Thank you all - I found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585649/exit-c-sharp-application-from-second-form

Comment: @DaGbyte - Note that the accepted answer there says that the approach is not recommended. It really can lead to many issues, file corruption being one of them. It is always better to exit gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the expected behaviour.

Try this code:

```
var f = new Form();
f.Click += (s, e) => Application.Exit();
Application.Run(f);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

The word `Hello` is not displayed to the console until the form is clicked on or it is closed.

`Application.Run` holds execution until an `Application.Exit()` call, or the main form closes, then execution continues. `Application.Exit()` doesn't abort threads or close the process - it just closes all forms and cleans up the message pump and allows the calling code to continue.